# A question related to when is F Galois over K and when F is splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, separable-extension

This question was part of my abstract algebra assignment and I was unable to solve 1 part among it. So, I am posting it here as I need help.

> Suppose [F : K] is finite. Then the following conditions are equivalent :
> (i) F is Galois over K ;
> (ii) F is separable over K and a splitting field of a polynomial f $\in$ K[x] ;
> (iii) F is a splitting field over K of a polynomial $f \in  K[x]$ whose irreducible
> factors are separable.

I am having problem only in the part in which I ahve to assume (iii) and prove (i) holds.

Can you please help with that? I have to prove that $Aut_K F = K $ itself. But i don't see any reason why it should hold.

Do you mind giving some hints.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your definition of 'Galois-extension' in the finite case is $F^{Aut_KF}=K$. Hints:

1. First conclude from the given assumptions in (iii) that $F/K$ is normal and separable.
2. Then show that in general for a normal extension $F/K$ we have that $F^{Aut_KF}$ is purely inseparable over $K$ by showing that there is only one $K$-homomorphism $F^{Aut_KF}\to C$ where $C$ is some algebraic closure of $F$.
3. Conclude under the additional assumption $F/K$ separable that $F^{Aut_KF}=F$ holds.