# Need help in completing the question related to proving these 4 conditions equivalent related to perfect fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Consider the following question:

> (a) The following conditions on a field K are equivalent :So, Prove them

> (i) every irreducible polynomial in K[x] is separable ;

> (ii) every algebraic closure K of K is Galois over K;

> (iii) every algebraic extension field of K is separable over K;

> (iv) either char K = 0 or char K = p and $K = K^p$.

(i)=>(ii)  This part I am not able to do. What i am missing is how to prove that for all $\sigma \in Aut_K{\bar K}$ only y$\in K$ gets fixed and rest all are not fixed.

(ii)=> (iii) I have done as if  an algebraic extension is galois over K and then the extension is also separable  over K ( This is a theorem).

(iii)=>(iv) I tried by assuming that char K $\neq 0$, so, As field is integral domain, so Characterstic must be prime and so, let char K=p but then I am not able to move towards proving $K=K^{p}$.

(iv)=>(i) I have solved . So, I don't require help with that.

Kindly shed some light on this

Comment: What are you allowed to use? That $f$ is separable iff $gcd(f,f')=1$?

Comment: See also the answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143828/question-about-a-property-certain-algebraic-extensions-e-k-not-necessarily-se).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I am allowed to use that.

Answer (score 0):

For (i)=>(ii): Let $L$ be an algebraic closure of $K$. Then $L/K$ is by definition normal and by assumption separable. Depending on your definition of Galois-extension we might be done here. If your definition of Galois extension is $K=L^{Aut_KL}$, then look at the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983662/a-question-related-to-when-is-f-galois-over-k-and-when-f-is-splitting-field/3983694#3983694) to one of your previous questions.
For (iii)=>(iv): If $a\in K$ there is some $b\in L$ in an extension field with $b^p=a$. Now look at the irreducible factors (over $K$) of the polynomial $x^p-a=(x-b)^p$ and use your assumption.

Comment: Why is in $(iii) \to (iv) $ there exists some $b\in L$ in an extension field with $b^p =a$? can you please tell?